# How do I prevent Word from starting in safe mode?

Tags: c#, ms-word, registry, window-handles, safe-mode

I've an applications that allows a user to start MS Word.
If the user holds the "CTRL" key while starting MS Word, following dialog is shown:

[image]

This leads to errors in my application, because users seem to hold the "CTRL" key by accident and may click on "yes", which deactivates my office addins.
Is there a way to prevent Word from showing this dialog and also from starting in safe mode?
For instance, if you try to start Excel with the "\e" parameter + holding "CTRL" key, Excel starts without any dialog and not in safe mode.

The application is developed in .Net (c#)

Answer (score 0):

**You tell the user to stop doing that!**

AFAIK, There is no way you can, with code or otherwise, stop Word from starting in safe mode. That is a basic diagnostic built into the programs and is not optional.

Comment: If you try to start Excel with the "\e" parameter + holding "CTRL" key, Excel starts without any dialog and not in safe mode. So, there is a way, at least for Excel....I'll add that to my question....

Comment: I assume you are familiar with the command-line switches for Word.
 * https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/command-line-switches-for-microsoft-office-products-079164cd-4ef5-4178-b235-441737deb3a6
 * Perhaps the /ttemplatename switch will do this. I do not know. None are documented as avoiding safemode. How is it that you have uses casually holding down the Ctrl key. Seems very curious to me.

Comment: /q starts without the splash screen. -- again, not documented to stop safe mode, but the /e switch in Excel is not documented to stop safe mode, either.